# Interpreting coefficients of a two-way logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic

I have the following binary variable Y to be predicted as a function of two factors, say X1 and X2. The whole file is available [here](https://tqmp.org/house/Example2.csv). X1 is binary and X2, categorical. When compiled, we find these proportions of 1s:

|  | X2=0 | X2=1 | X2=2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X1 = 0 | 75/89 (84.3%) | 62/77 (80.5%) | 40/52 (76.9%) |
| X1 = 1 | 84/92 (91.3%) | 52/72 (72.2%) | 42/63 (66.6%) |

Running with R a logistic regression using

```
M <- glm(Y ~ X1 + X2 + X1 : X2, family=binomial, data=dta)
summary(M)
```

we obtain the following coefficients:

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   1.6713     0.2661   6.280 3.39e-10 ***
X1            0.3995     0.3957   1.009    0.313    
X2           -0.2382     0.2186  -1.090    0.276    
X1:X2        -0.5308     0.3022  -1.757    0.079 .
```

The intercept is straigthforward to interpret: un-logit this number $e^{1.67} / (1+ e^{1.67}) = .843$ is indeed the proportion obtained in the cell with factors X1,X2 = 0, 0.

To predict the result where X2 is 0 and X1 is 1, the log odd change is $e^{0.3995} = 1.49$, that is, that condition is 49% more present than the intercept. However, this equals $1.49 \times 0.844 = 1.257$ which is more than 100% of ones in that condition.

I must be doing something wrong, because this is a very poor fit to the data. Likewise, if I continue looking at the predictions for the other cells, I find more bad fits along with some accurate fits. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coefficient for `X1` is the *difference in log-odds* from the intercept, when `X1 = 1` and `X2 = 0`. So you need to calculate:

```
exp(1.6713+0.3995)/(1+exp(1.6713+0.3995))
# [1] 0.8880325
```

which is pretty close to what you observed.

The results aren't exact because you seem to have modeled `X2` as a numeric variable rather than as a categorical predictor. You only have a single `X1:X2` interaction coefficient. If you had modeled `X2` as a 3-level categorical predictor you would have 2 such coefficients.

Comment: Thanks. How could I model X2 as categorical? Would spitting X2 into indicators X2a and X2b be enough?

Comment: @DenisCousineau let the software do it for you. In R: `facX2 <- factor(X2)`. It's too easy to make mistakes when you try to do things like this yourself.

Comment: Great, thank you!